# filter empty array fields in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

My document structure is something like:

```
{
    title: string,
    description: string,
    privacy_mode: string,
    hidden: boolean,
    added_by: string,
    topics: array
}
```

I am trying to query elasticsearch. However I dont want any document with empty topics array field.

Below is a function which builds the query object:

```
function getQueryObject(data) {
    var orList = [{ "term": {"privacy_mode": "public", "hidden": false} }]
    if (data.user) {
        orList.push({ "term": {"added_by": data.user} });
    }

    var queryObj = {
        "fields": ["title", "topics", "added_by", "img_url", "url", "type"],
        "query": {
            "filtered" : {
                "query" : {
                    "multi_match" : {
                        "query" : data.query + '*',
                        "fields" : ["title^4", "topics", "description^3", "tags^2", "body^2", "keywords",
                                "entities", "_id"]
                    }
                },
                "filter" : {
                    "or": orList
                },
                "filter" : {
                    "limit" : {"value" : 15}
                },
                "filter": {
                   "script": {
                        "script": "doc['topics'].values.length > 0"
                   }
               }
            }
        }
    }
    return queryObj;
};
```

This still gives me elements with empty topics array. wondering whats wrong!

Thank for the help

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You probably want the [missing-filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-missing-filter.html). Your script approach will load *all* the values of topics into memory, which will be very wasteful if you are not also e.g. faceting on them.

Also, the structure of your filter is wrong. You cannot have repeated values for `filter`, but should wrap them with a `bool`-filter. (Here is why you usually want to use `bool` and not `and|or|not`: http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/all-about-elasticsearch-filter-bitsets/

Lastly, you probably want to specify the `size` on the search object, instead of using the `limit`-filter.

I made a runnable example you can play with: https://www.found.no/play/gist/aa59b987269a24feb763

```
#!/bin/bash

export ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT="http://localhost:9200"

# Index documents
curl -XPOST "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/_bulk?refresh=true" -d '
{"index":{"_index":"play","_type":"type"}}
{"privacy_mode":"public","topics":["foo","bar"]}
{"index":{"_index":"play","_type":"type"}}
{"privacy_mode":"private","topics":[]}
'

# Do searches

curl -XPOST "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/_search?pretty" -d '
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "privacy_mode": "public"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "must_not": [
                        {
                            "missing": {
                                "field": "topics"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

Comment: Thanks alex. I think you are right in most part of it. I will make the changes accordingly. As for missing filter, I dont know if it will work. 'topics: []' is present the document. its empty not missing.

Comment: Hi alex, Missing worked very well. However using bool will break my logic. What i am trying to do is select document which are either public or added by the logged in user. Hence i used or filter. What do you think about this case?

Comment: `bool`'s `should` corresponds to `or`. Note that you can nest `bool`s as well.

Comment: Does'nt work for me, the same query but for 'nested' type of array.

Comment: @FelikZ, see this answer regarding `nested` and `bool`s: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691882/nested-filter-query-with-exclusionary-ors/21709549#21709549

Comment: @AlexBrasetvik thank you, it is very helpful! Also if we need do reverse search, here is example how to do it: http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/missing-filter-with-nested-objects-td4044368.html

Comment: The missing-filter is dead. Here is the one for ES 2.4: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/query-dsl-missing-filter.html. This link says that you have now to use the [Missing Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/query-dsl-missing-query.html) which is deprecated since ES 2.2.0 and now you have to use the [Exists Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/query-dsl-exists-query.html)

Answer (score 16):

The keyword `missing` is remove since ES5.0 and it suggests using `exists`(see [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/query-dsl-exists-query.html)):

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: 
application/json' -d'
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": {
                   "exists": {
                       "field": "topics"
                   }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Comment: "must" "exists"?