# Nested Filter Query with Exclusionary ORs

Tags: search, lucene, elasticsearch

I am unable to restrict the result set to documents that match both `kol_tags.scored.name` and `kol_tags.scored.score` range for both the `or` options below.

I would like to match documents that have the `kol_tags.scored.name` of "Core Grower" and `kol_tags.scored.score` between 1 and 100 unless they also have `kol_tags.scored.name` of "Connectivity" where `kol_tags.scored.score` is **NOT** in the range of 35 to 65.

Given the following mapping (non nested fields omitted for brevity):

```
GET /production_users/user/_mapping
{
  "user": {
    "_all": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "properties": {
      "kol_tags": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "scored": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {                  
              "name": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed",
                "omit_norms": true,
                "index_options": "docs"
              },
              "score": {
                "type": "integer"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am executing the following query:

```
{
  "filter": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "kol_tags.scored",
      "filter": {
        "or": [
          {
            "and": [                  
              {
                "terms": {
                  "kol_tags.scored.name": [
                    "Core Grower"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "kol_tags.scored.score": {
                    "gte": 1,
                    "lte": 100
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "and": [                  
              {
                "terms": {
                  "kol_tags.scored.name": [
                    "Connectivity"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "kol_tags.scored.score": {
                    "gte": 35,
                    "lte": 65
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With the query above I get documents that match `kol_tags.scored.name` of "Core Grower" and `kol_tags.scored.score` between 1 and 100 and **ALSO** that have `kol_tags.scored.name` of "Connectivity" and `kol_tags.scored.score` in any range.

What I need is documents that match:

- `kol_tags.scored.name` of "Core Grower" and `kol_tags.scored.score` between 1 and 100
- `kol_tags.scored.name` of "Connectivity" and `kol_tags.scored.score` between 35 and 65
- **Exclude any documents that have `kol_tags.scored.name` of "Connectivity" and `kol_tags.scored.score` less than 34 and greater than 66**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some ambiguity in your description, but I've tried to make a runnable example that should work here: https://www.found.no/play/gist/8940202 (also embedded below)

Here's a few things I did:

- Put the filter in a `filtered`-query. A top level `filter` (renamed to `post_filter` in Elasticsearch 1.0) should only be used if you want to filter hits, but not facets.
- Use `bool` instead of `and` and `or`, since the filters are cachable. More here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/all-about-elasticsearch-filter-bitsets/
- And most importantly, put the `nested` *inside* the `bool`, so the logic gets right wrt. what should match on the nested vs. the parent document.
- Added a `must_not` to account for your last point. Not sure if you can have two sub-documents with name `"Connectivity"`, but if you can, that should account for it. If you'll only ever have one, you can remove the `must_not`.

You didn't provide any sample documents, so I made some I think should fit your description. I don't think you need two levels of nested.

```
#!/bin/bash

export ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT="http://localhost:9200"

# Create indexes

curl -XPUT "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/play" -d '{
    "mappings": {
        "type": {
            "properties": {
                "kol_tags": {
                    "properties": {
                        "scored": {
                            "type": "nested",
                            "properties": {
                                "name": {
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'

# Index documents
curl -XPOST "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/_bulk?refresh=true" -d '
{"index":{"_index":"play","_type":"type"}}
{"kol_tags":{"scored":[{"name":"Core Grower","score":36},{"name":"Connectivity","score":42}]}}
{"index":{"_index":"play","_type":"type"}}
{"kol_tags":{"scored":[{"name":"Connectivity","score":34},{"name":"Connectivity","score":42}]}}
{"index":{"_index":"play","_type":"type"}}
{"kol_tags":{"scored":[{"name":"Core Grower","score":36}]}}
{"index":{"_index":"play","_type":"type"}}
{"kol_tags":{"scored":[{"name":"Connectivity","score":36}]}}
'

# Do searches

curl -XPOST "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/_search?pretty" -d '
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                        {
                            "nested": {
                                "path": "kol_tags.scored",
                                "filter": {
                                    "bool": {
                                        "must": [
                                            {
                                                "term": {
                                                    "name": "Core Grower"
                                                }
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "range": {
                                                    "score": {
                                                        "gte": 1,
                                                        "lte": 100
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "nested": {
                                "path": "kol_tags.scored",
                                "filter": {
                                    "bool": {
                                        "must": [
                                            {
                                                "term": {
                                                    "name": "Connectivity"
                                                }
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "range": {
                                                    "score": {
                                                        "gte": 35,
                                                        "lte": 65
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "must_not": [
                        {
                            "nested": {
                                "path": "kol_tags.scored",
                                "filter": {
                                    "bool": {
                                        "must": [
                                            {
                                                "term": {
                                                    "name": "Connectivity"
                                                }
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "not": {
                                                    "range": {
                                                        "score": {
                                                            "gte": 35,
                                                            "lte": 65
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
'

curl -XPOST "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/_search?pretty" -d '
{
    "filter": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "kol_tags.scored",
            "filter": {
                "or": [
                    {
                        "and": [
                            {
                                "terms": {
                                    "kol_tags.scored.name": [
                                        "Core Grower"
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "range": {
                                    "kol_tags.scored.score": {
                                        "gte": 1,
                                        "lte": 100
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "and": [
                            {
                                "terms": {
                                    "kol_tags.scored.name": [
                                        "Connectivity"
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "range": {
                                    "kol_tags.scored.score": {
                                        "gte": 35,
                                        "lte": 65
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```